# Tune Spark and YARN properties in HDP Sandbox

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using HDP sandbox 3.1 and performing NLTK on 50K files using spark2 Interpreter and Zeppelin Notebook.
It's a single node setup.

I've given 12GB RAM to Guest System and 6CPUs.

In spark, I'm reading all 50K files in a single RDD Operation, but at 63% my process hangs, and then it leads to ERROR.

Now which Values in Spark and YARN I've to set, so Spark can work in full throttle.

Edit: Each file size is around 3KB

Following is the log when Error occurred

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1361)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1930)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anon$3.run(SparkContext.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.\n', JavaObject id=o101)
```

Comment: What's spark configurations you are passing ?

Comment: @rj087 I've kept the value of "spark.cores.max ","spark.executor.memory" blank in Spark2 Interpreter settings in Zeppelin Service. [https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#configuration]

If I change these values Spark program becomes slow.

and I can even set values in the program using SparkConf.set()